# When i try apt-get update on backtrack 5r3 it doesnt work

Tags: apt, backtrack-linux

it says failed to fetch http://some urls..

and E:Some index files failed to download,they have been ignored,or old ones used instead. what i am doing with that code "apt-get update"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to remove the Repository(URLS) that is not able to fetch from  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then you run: 
1: 
`aptitude clean` (cleans all .deb "package stock" in /var/cache/apt/archives)
 (cleans all .deb "package stock" in /var/cache/apt/archives)

2

```
aptitude update
```

3

```
 aptitude full-upgrade
```

Good luck!

Best regards

Daniel